# I need to add field after function return something

Tags: jquery

I need to add field in error div once it returns list of elements containing error.

My function is on submit.

```
$("#form").on('submit', function (event) {
return checkInputFields {formParam: this});
$("#fErrors ul").append('<li id="customError">Please tick one checkbox in Role</li>');
});
```

Once i get the error div then only i can add my li to it.But that is not happening.

Comment: `checkInputFields {formParam: this});` Syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The return happens and the function ends. Move it to the end:

```
$("#form").on('submit', function (event) {
    var isValid = checkInputFields({formParam: this});
    $("#fErrors ul").append('<li id="customError">Please tick one checkbox in Role</li>');
    return isValid;
});
```

Comment: syntax error - var isValid = checkInputFields {formParam: this});

Comment: @Sudharsan you missed '(' after 'checkInputFields', which exists in this answer.